# How to get selected value for dropdown list inside gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu

**Scenarios**

I am using `DataGrid` with a column containing `DropDownList`. When I update the values, the `DropDownList` value does not get updated.

**My Research so far**

I believe it needs some C# code to made the `DropDownList` editable. I don't know where to put the code and how? Is there a shorter way than C# code?

Thank you very much

**Edit : Supplied Code**

student_table : id, name, major, favorite_teacher

teacher_table : id, name

The gridview has datasource of student. The `DropDownList` has datasource of teacher.

In the gridview with, I have made favorite_teacher as template field (`DropDownList`) and has teacher_table as datasource. In the edit mode, the `DropDownList` shows correct and populates teachers from the teacher table. When I select a favourite teacher for any student and click submit, the submit does not go through. I might need some C# code or otherwise. Don't know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this from a tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) without writing any C# code.

You do not need C# code, although you can implement it using C# code as well.

There is a trick that you have to implement. You need to bind the values of gridview to a datasource of the other table that you want to fetch data from. But by design, since dropdown list is contained in GridView, it can only be bound to gridview fields. This is the main complication.

To overcome that, include those additional fields in the gridview. You may need to use join statement so that you can include all the fields that you need in gridview. Now you can easily bind those fields to DropDownlist. Of course you do not need to show these extra values in GridView, they are there only for DropDownList. This will solve your problem, without writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code and let me know if it's fixed:

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tmpValue = ((DropDownList)gvRowItem.Cells[/*cellId*/].FindControl("/*dropDownListId*/")).SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

DataSourceID="sds_teacher_table" is referring to the teacher_table. the gridview will be referring to the student_table

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Favourite Teacher" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfavorite_teacher" runat="server" Text='<%# LookupTeacherName(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")) %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfavorite_teacher" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_teacher_table" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("id")%>' Width="98%">
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewfavorite_teacher" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_teacher_table" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("id")%>' Width="95%">
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </FooterTemplate>
               <ItemStyle Width="25%" /> 
           </asp:TemplateField>


    protected string LookupTeacherName(object idObj)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idObj.ToString()))
            return null;

        string TeacherId = idObj.ToString();

        // find the corresponding name
        IEnumerator enumos = sds_teacher_table.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments()).GetEnumerator();
        while (enumos.MoveNext())
        {
            DataRowView row = enumos.Current as DataRowView;

            if ((string)row["id"].ToString() == TeacherId)
                return string.Concat(row["name"].ToString());
        }

        return TeacherId;
    }
```

Comment: I did some research since then and now what I found out is that I need to bind the dropdownlist to the dropdown datasource, rathan than the gridview datasource. By default it give me the parameters of gridview. My Dropdownlist is sitting inside the gridview. Please comment if you have answer.

Comment: Even if the dropdown list sitting inside the gridview you can mention a different datasource and bind the data, You have to mention the datasource name in the 


 DataSourceID="sqlDS_name" field. 
If you couldn't find the answer please elaborate your issue with some value or with an example.

Comment: I have attached a sample code and explained it a little more. If you have question, please post it here. Thank you

Comment: @Dave : I have updated the code, please try with the above code and let us know if it is working.

Comment: It is a little complicated. I could not implement the whole thing as some of your variables name are different than mine. But you got the whole Idea. Now when I look at your approach, it does not update the database, does it? In my GridView1, I used Update Query before. Now I have changed that to storedProcedure to make it simple. I would actually like the commited value to be updated in the database table, and fetch it from there to display. Will send you the new code, please wait.

Comment: is the above code worked or are you going to post your code for debugging?

Comment: Hey gvLeaner, Thanks a bunch for the code. It did not work for me out of the box and I did not spend a huge time on it because I dont see where it stores the values in the database, which i needed. So I changed my query and implemented above behavior without writing a single line of c# code. It was quite a bit of headache. The trick is to modify the select query so it includes all the fields that you need in gridview: You have to use join in this case. Thank you again!